# Fetch for timestamp using PERL regex

Tags: regex, perl, timestamp

I am having difficulties picking up a timestamp where day, month and year are separated by a dot, although the regular expression i chose seems to work just fine when the matching is done just once.

Here is my text line:

```
TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016 00:33:01
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#looking for timestamp in the following format: TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016   00:33:01

my $TIMESTAMP;
my $TXT;

$TXT = "TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016 00:33:01";

#matching for MACRO. example:   TIMESTAMP: 2016-09-18T15:07:20.246Z
($TIMESTAMP = $TXT) =~ /^TIMESTAMP: ([0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9] {1,2})T([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}).[0-9]+Z/;
print "\ncheck1)the TIMESTAMP value is:$TIMESTAMP\n";
if (! defined $1) {

#matching for MM. example:  TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016 00:33:01
($TIMESTAMP = $TXT) =~ /^TIMESTAMP: ((?:\d+).(?:\d+).(?:\d+))\s((?:\d+):(?:\d+):(?:\d+))/;
print   "check2)the TIMESTAMP value is:$TIMESTAMP\n";
}

if (defined $1 and defined $2) {
    $TIMESTAMP = $1." ".$2;
    print "the timestamp is:$TIMESTAMP\n";
} else {
        
    $TIMESTAMP = "n/a\n";
    print "not all elements of TIMESTAMP were defined,   TIMESTAMP:$TIMESTAMP\n";
}
```

I used [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/) to verify that the regular expression works, but when I do two checks in a row the script fails to deliver the groups `$1` and `$2`.

#### Update

Tidied Perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Looking for timestamp in the following format: TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016   00:33:01

my $TIMESTAMP;
my $TXT;

$TXT = "TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016 00:33:01";

# Matching for MACRO. example:   TIMESTAMP: 2016-09-18T15:07:20.246Z

( $TIMESTAMP = $TXT ) =~ /^TIMESTAMP: ([0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9] {1,2})T([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}).[0-9]+Z/;

print "\ncheck1) the TIMESTAMP value is:$TIMESTAMP\n";

if ( ! defined $1 ) {

    # matching for MM. example:  TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016 00:33:01
    
    ( $TIMESTAMP = $TXT ) =~ /^TIMESTAMP: ((?:\d+).(?:\d+).(?:\d+))\s((?:\d+):(?:\d+):(?:\d+))/;

    print "check2)the TIMESTAMP value is:$TIMESTAMP\n";
}

if ( defined $1 and defined $2 ) {

    $TIMESTAMP = $1 . " " . $2;

    print "the timestamp is:$TIMESTAMP\n";
}
else {

    $TIMESTAMP = "n/a\n";

    print "not all elements of TIMESTAMP were defined,   TIMESTAMP:$TIMESTAMP\n";
}
```

Comment: A literal dot in the pattern should be escaped. Also, `(?:\d+)` = `\d+`. Try [`/^TIMESTAMP: (\d+\.\d+.\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+:\d+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/jlRqiV/2)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, notice that i perform two checks, first for a timestamp where a hyphen is used to separate day, month, year. If that pattern is not found then i check for a dot (.) as separator...but no matter what regular expression i used (yours or mine) it fails to pick up $1 and $2.

Comment: Your Perl code is very hard to read. Can you not use spaces to add layout and make it more readable?

Comment: thanks, i'll keep that mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine, but you have made it overly complicated

- Your comments are wrong, and don't even agree with one another
- There is no need to enclose every `\d+` in a regex pattern inside `(?: ... )`
- You must escape a literal dot `.` in a regex pattern, otherwise it can match any character
- It is best to use the `/x` modifier with a regex pattern that isn't trivial, so that you can add spaces to make it more readable
- The capture variables `$1`, `$2` ... are block scoped, but you expect them to be permanent

Here's a version that works, and uses `Data::Dump` to show the captured values at a couple of points in the code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my $text = "TIMESTAMP: 08.08.2016 00:33:01";

unless ( defined $1 ) {

    $text =~ / ^ TIMESTAMP: \s* (\d+\.\d+\.\d+) \s+ (\d+:\d+:\d+) /x;

    dd [ $1, $2 ];
}

dd [ $1, $2 ];
```

#### output

```
["08.08.2016", "00:33:01"]
[undef, undef]
```